# Как удалить строку из текста

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

подскажите, как удалить строку из текста начинающеюся с определенного слова ?
Есть текст, в нем есть строка, начинается со слова - Оплачивается. Надо удалить все предложение до точки.
Нашел тут похожий вопрос, пробовал приведенное там решение

```
echo preg_replace('/[\.]+Оплачивается \d+ ./', '', $string);
```

не срабатывает.

Comment: Так, всё-таки, строку или предложение? Если второе, то могут ли в предложении встречаться точки, например, в числах?

Comment: Пример строки из которой нужно удалить - в студию!

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/9wO8n9/1

Comment: предложение. нет, точек там не будет. но если это так существенно то окончание - тираж.

Comment: @freestd вы нормально напишите варианты. Если заканчивается всегда одним словом, до которого надо удалить, то очевидно об этом надо написать.

Comment: вариант предложенный @teran отлично срабатывает. всем спасибо. вопрос можно закрыть. не знаю можно ли тут как отметить ответ решением или как то еще его отметить.

Comment: вы ответьте сначала на вопросы про окончания предложения. Если у вас удалять надо все до слова "тираж", то выражение можно написать гораздо проще

Comment: @teran удалять надо все от слова Оплачивается до слова тираж. Вместе с этими словами, то есть все это предложение, между этими словами текст может меняться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для удаления фрагмента от "Оплачивается" до конца предложения можно использовать выражение `(\s|^)Оплачивается.*?\.(?=\s|$)`. То есть фрагмент начинается от начала строки, или после пробела. Затем идет Оплачивается и произвольный текст, после чего точки. За точкой следует либо пробел, либо конец строки.

```
preg_replace("/(\s|^)Оплачивается.*?\.(?=\s|$)/u", $txt, "");
```

Если же у вас надо удалить от слова Оплачивается до тираж, то все будет проще

```
preg_replace("/Оплачивается.*?тираж/u", ....);
```